# How to read test logs

Tags: java, maven

I have run a maven test now I have the logs for it but where exactly in that big log file can found what exactly the error its pointing out to. All I see when go down bottom its says faliure with exception message null and than functional clas test name and othe id names?

Comment: Please post the actual exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Tests that fail get logged in their respective test report files.

When there are errors `mvn test` will lead to this:
 <sup>*(assuming typical surefire usage)*</sup>

```
[ERROR] Please refer to .../project/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
```

If you look in that directory, you'll see something like this: <sup>*(specific to your project)*</sup>

```
some.rnd.pkg.AnyGivenTest.txt
```

<sup>*(Depending on your configuration, you may have XML instead, or in addition, etc. The XML has significant other information as well, like classpath and property info--it can be very handy sometimes, although generally the stack trace is enough.)*</sup>

Stack traces are in there.

Comment: I think the OP have already looked at the log files (states so in the post) -- the question is more about deciphering the meaning and the cause of the failure

Comment: @Attila Could be; hard to tell--if that ends up being the case, I'll delete this answer.